# Problem with plot using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the exponential function [image] using `pgfplots`, but no matter what I change, I get only a part of the plot.

Here's the code (the code and the image were made using exp(0.25x) instead of exp(0.25x-5) but I get a similar result in both cases anyway):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\hspace{15mm}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=1,ylabel= $\mathbb{P}(x)$,xlabel=$x$, 
no markers,samples=100,grid=both]
\addplot {1/(1+exp(0.25*x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the plot I get:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `domain=-5:15` solves the issue for both functions:

[image]

### Notes:

- I am not sure why `pgfplots` did not just extract the domain from `xmin` and `xmax`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\hspace{15mm}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=1,ylabel= $\mathbb{P}(x)$,xlabel=$x$, 
no markers,samples=100,grid=both,domain=-5:15]
\addplot+ [ultra thick] {1/(1+exp(0.25*x))};
\addplot+ [ultra thick] {1/(1+exp(0.25*x-5))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem, I didn't know I had to indicate the domain. Thanks again.